# Poor boot-screen after interrupted install

Tags: boot, nvidia, plymouth

My install was interrupted because of a power cut. I recovered from it, using the command

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now, I get a violet boot screen like normal, but the progress bar is shown as 4 dots, and Ubuntu is displayed in a simple font, reminiscent of the DOS era. What do I do to make it right? I have Nvidia drivers. Also, worth mentioning is that before showing the boot screen, I get a line of text saying:

```
............ unreliable temperature sensor.............
```

I use a [Asus M3N78-EM](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M3N78EM/specifications/), AMD Phenom II X3 720 Black Edition, 4GB DDR2, Nvidia 9400GT 512 MB.

Thanks.

Comment: I use a Asus M3N78-EM AMD Phenom II X3 720 Black Edition 4GB DDR2, Nvidia 9400GT 512 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Install **cryptsetup** package (side effect of this action is logo normalization)

Answer (score 0):

A clean install with power during the entire process will do the trick in the safest way.

Comment: I cant do that, because I have lots of packages and settings installed. But Open Help's answer did the trick.

Comment: Sure, Open Help's answer is very usefull I said this because "an inrerupted installation process" always scares me. I don't have deep technical knowledge on the subject, its just a feeling. I hope there aren't more broken things.

Answer (score 0):

To recover from a broken install without loosing configuration, you can :

1. [boot on live usb](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
2. [make backup of broken system from live usb](https://askubuntu.com/a/78699/458410)
3. [fresh re-install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) (with preserve `/home` option)
4. restore any config files you need from backup made in step 2.
5. reinstall packages

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's the boot-screen.

***Sidenote:** No, I'm not gonna argue about the design...what you see is the right and perfect working boot screen.*

Comment: Umm no, thats not the perfect bootscreen, because its not like the one that was in 10.4. If you say that this ( http://ubuntica.com/wp-content/images/2010/03/ubuntu-lucid-boot-screen.png) is the correct boot screen, then its not what I see.

Comment: What I see is this: 
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_JBHfzEovWs8/S6bkMaV4EaI/AAAAAAAAALM/ea_Od2957t0/s1600-h/lubuntu+boot.png

Comment: @theTuxRacer: Yes, that's the boot screen I also have.