# Plymouth ugly with nvidia driver (fix tuto don't support my resolution)

Tags: nvidia, plymouth

I recently buy a 1366x768 laptop with nvidia gts 360m (asus G60Jx-rbbx05). I installed the nvidia driver version 256.53 for compatibility issue and now work great. I followed multiple tutorial to fix the very ugly plymouth boot, but no one support 1366x768, and only support 1024x768. Can I get a normal plymouth with the nvidia driver?

Comment: Could be a duplicate, but I'm not sure: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8740/poor-boot-screen-after-interrupted-install/8754#8754

Comment: no, it's a similar problem but it can be solve easily with the incalculable number of tutorial you can found on google but grub don't support my own. I see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen and I followed the two tutorial, without success. I just see 1024x768 in my supported resolution

Comment: the supported resolution is hardware related, I'm sorry but you might have to stick with 1024x768

Answer (score 2):

These [two](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen/6040#6040) [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen/6074#6074) to this [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen) rely on hardware support.  Specifically, they rely on the VESA modes available in your video BIOS.  This should always contain the default VESA resolutions but it's also possible for the laptop or video card manufacturer to add extra resolutions - such as 1366x768 - to this table.  Sometimes manufacturers don't add any extra resolutions here, as it's only useful for *really* old applications that want to use the VESA system or when proper drivers aren't installed.

Since at boot time we have *no* video driver available, just the VESA calls, we're limited to the resolutions in the VBIOS.  Anything else needs to wait until a hardware driver is loaded which can do proper resolution setting.

For the open-source drivers which support KMS we can load these early during startup, so we get a proper resolution quickly.  The `nvidia` and `fglrx` drivers need to wait until X is started, by which time there's no need for a splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

On my current and my previous laptop I could only use the 1024x768 resolution in grub and plymouth. This is probably because the drivers needs X to show a higher resolution.

Anyway, there is no way to change that, you will have to live with "only" 1024x768 until gdm starts.