# Resolve Big Ugly Plymouth Splash Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, radeon, plymouth, ati

I have tried with Plymouth Manager & also [here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml)

No joy.  Hardware is Lenovo ThinkPad Edge (E)325 with AMD Radeon discreet graphics.  Laptop is Ubuntu Certified & everything else works out of the box.

Please assist.

EDIT:  Splash was fine until an update broke correct resolution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plymouth ugly with nvidia driver (fix tuto don't support my resolution)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11821/plymouth-ugly-with-nvidia-driver-fix-tuto-dont-support-my-resolution)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to enabling the propriety graphics drivers. Plymouth then appears wrong resolution.

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem, or it's just a comment?