# How to copy files to an external HDD from Ubuntu live session?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a 320 Gigs HDD with no partition and Ubuntu installed on it, but I can't see the display when it enters lock screen or the desktop. I tried running Ubuntu through a live USB Flash drive and it worked perfectly. I must've done something at the terminal that the display goes off.

Anyways, now I'm thinking to copy my data to an external HDD and re-install Ubuntu. But when I try to copy any folder to external HDD it says "The folder 'folder name' cannot be handled because you do not have permissions to read it".Or when I open a folder it says "You don't have permissions necessary to view the contents of 'folder name'".
How can I get permissions to do so and copy the files to an external HDD, and re-install Ubuntu.

(The file system of the internal HDD is ext4 if that matters)

 Help me please!

Comment: Might this help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83268/how-do-i-get-root-access-to-hard-drive-from-livecd

Comment: Some of what you've said doesn't make sense; I would suggest editing for clarity on some parts. "no partition with Ubuntu installed" for example is physically impossible. "Can't see the display when it enters lock" Which display? You can change your power settings to prevent the lock screen. What is the location of the folders you are trying to copy?

Comment: If you right click on a folder and click properties you should be able to get owner ship and permission information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get around this by running your file manager with root priviledges. In your terminal type "`sudo nautilus`". You should now be able to access the folders and files so you can copy them.