# Ubuntu 10.04 cannot detect the monitor, low resolution produced, does this guide work?

Tags: resolution, screen

I am working in office and I can't risk to format my harddisk but my screen cannot detect native resolution (using wide screen), the max resolution it provdies is 1280x1024 and I want 1440x900. I am afraid i will do something wrong and cannot boot up the computer again later and need to reformat harddisk....

I found this [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1879121) useful but not sure does it reli work?

Does anyone can help me or comment this [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1879121)?
I don't have any nvidia or ati graphic card but only with intel onboard graphics display, the chipset should be intel H67 with sandy bridge. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that guide is likely be helpful.

More to the point, if you are careful, you wouldn't need to reformat even if it doesn't work.  By careful I mean:

1. Taking good notes about what changes you're making
2. Making backups of all files you change
3. Type carefully, or copy/paste commands

If you do these things and something goes wrong, worst case, you would need to use a liveCD to change the settings back to the way they were.

Comment: may i know more? What if sth doesn't work, and make it black screen if I boot up (cannot start up display), how can I revert it?

Comment: @KitHo Do you still have the CD (or DVD) from which Ubuntu was installed?  All recent ubuntu installatino CDs are liveCDs, which means you can boot up from them.  Put your CD into your CD drive, and restart your computer, it should boot from the CD.  Once you're running from the CD, connect to your harddrive and undo the changes you made (see http://askubuntu.com/a/78699/6161 for how to connect to your harddrive from a live CD)