# How to boot to recovery mode in 10.04? holding shift key doesn't work

Tags: boot, grub2, recovery-mode

i am going to try the guide inside this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117064/ubuntu-10-04-cannot-detect-the-monitor-low-resolution-produced-does-this-guide)

However, it requires me to boot from recovery mode.
But holding the shift key doesn't work for me to go to grub menu.

Anyone know how to troubleshoot this kind of behavior?

Kit

Comment: sometimes ESC (escape) key does this - can you give this a try?

Comment: have tried ESC...dont' work

Comment: @aking: what does it mean add tab to the list

Comment: try keys: tab. shift. and escape.

Comment: You are holding down the **left** Shift key, right?

Comment: @Sircharlo: i have tried both!, left and right

Comment: And you start holding it immediately after the BIOS screen disappears?

Comment: @SirCharlo: hold from startup to the login screen

Comment: :S That is really strange. Is grub2 your bootloader?

Comment: @SirCharlo: do u know how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Well, run [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/files/latest/download) to tell you what bootloader you're using.

Comment: I tap each key since holding makes my BIOS loading grind to a halt

Comment: Are you able to access any BIOS menus? Sometimes (especially with older computers and USB keyboards) the BIOS can't get input from the keyboard even when the OS can once it's booted. GRUB by default uses BIOS calls to access the keyboard, but it can also be configured to use native drivers to work around this problem. But if you can access BIOS menus then this is not the problem you're having.

Comment: @Jordan, I can access the boot menu by pressing 'del" button. then i try to reboot my computer, keep holding shift key (right), the boot menu still didn't boot up. Is there any alternative way to boot to recovery mode?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can't boot into a "normal" session and need recovery mode for repairs...Would it work for you to boot a live CD and make the repairs that way?

Comment: yes i need recovery mode for repairs? any alterative solution?