# Why does the installer say I don't have enough drive space on a new drive?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, hard-drive, disk-usage, ubiquity

I have a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am trying to install it on a new (bare) hard drive and can't get past the first screen (the one that says "For best results, please ensure that this computer: has at least 4.4 GB available drive space"). There is a big X by that but I know there is plenty of drive space, it is a 1 TB hard drive and has NOTHING on it. Has anyone else had this problem?

It had gone past that before, up to the part where it was supposedly creating the ext 4 file system--after about 15 minutes or so it would get a black screen and nothing else happened. I am stumped.

Comment: Does the new drive show up in BIOS? Also make sure its not formatted or partitioned.

Comment: Takkat, sorry I missed your post until now. No, the new drive is not formatted or partitioned, just a straight out of the box Western Digital.

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt the installation, have you checked whether your drive shows up in any of the included programs (such as Nautilus or Disk Utility), and if you can mount it? If it does not appear there, you may want to check your drive was properly installed and all connections are secure.

Comment: I installed the hard drive and I am sure it is installed correctly. And I don't know how I would go about checking Nautilus or Disk Utility on a cd/system that is yet to be installed. As far as I can tell there is no program on the live cd that can even tell me what hardware my computer has.

Comment: Are you clicking "Install Ubuntu" or "Try Ubuntu" at the initial screen after the LiveCD/USB has loaded? If you click the latter, you'll be able to run the Ubuntu desktop and get to Nautilus (the file manager) at least. Look at the second paragraph of [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/78699/18612) for information on how to mount your drive from Nautilus after you start it.

Comment: I am using Try Ubuntu. Of course I was using Install Ubuntu before it weirded out on me and couldn't find the space it needed on the hard drive. Thanks for your help. I will see if I can find Nautilus (so far I had seen no mention of it, only something that looked like a Nautilus shell when it was loading).

Comment: The name "Nautilus" won't appear directly in the GUI, unless you view its About information. It will probably be called "Files" and appear as the first default icon in the Unity launcher under the Dash home button. If in doubt, you can also run it manually from a terminal or Alt+F2: `nautilus` Sorry if I'm being confusing!

Comment: Thank you. No, you are not being confusing. I ran nautilus as a command from F2 and besides one thing that says Nautilus which, if you click on it, shows home and some other stuff, there is also nautilus-autorun-software, nautilus-connect-server and nautilus-sendto. Should I click on any of those? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Nope, we want just plain `nautilus` (the window which shows your home folder, etc.). Look along the top-left side of that window for a section called "Devices"; if Ubuntu can detect your installed drive, it should appear there, and you can click it to mount it. ([Example picture.](http://i.imgur.com/pO87e.png)) Does your drive show in that list?

Comment: No, unfortunately mine doesn't have any of that. When I click on the Dash Home button I get several things but nothing having to do with nautilus and nothing that shows any devices.