# login loop- "system problem detected" ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login

it won't let me log into my account, it asks for my password (which it never did before on startup) and when i enter it the screen goes black and then back to the purple login page. as soon as i turn the computer on a "system error detected" message appears, and again when i try to sign in. It's not a password issue, as when I enter in a different password it gives me an "incorrect password" message, but not when I use the correct one.
It does let me log in as a guest but I urgently need to retrieve a very important file from my account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (please bear in mind that I have absolutely no idea how linux works and have great difficulties understanding the commands etc!!) Thanks

Comment: ps.  if there is any way to retrieve the file using the guest account please let me know too! (as it is absolutely crucial I retrieve it, all the rest I don't care about, and I will then try and re-install windows, I can't be dealing with this stress!!)

Comment: @dwen Guest accounts on Ubuntu are restricted (with AppArmor) from accessing any files in other user accounts' home directories. Since the most immediately important task is to recover the files, I think you should [boot from a live CD/DVD/USB and copy them off that way](https://askubuntu.com/q/78691/22949). (You can still attempt to fix the underlying login loop problem afterwards, of course.)