# Ubuntu server crashes on boot "end trace 3b4c21cd8473b17e"

Tags: boot, data-recovery, crash

System info:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- software RAID, no separate drive for OS

This is where the system crashes:

[image: Crash Screen]

I am hoping for help recovering at least enough to copy the files off the system.

**Update:**

I feel like there are two answers to my problem; one is fixing the OS so that it will boot again and the second is copying the files off. As long as I can save my files I am happy.

- I tried using the *Advanced Options for Ubuntu* to pick an older kernel and as far as I can tell this does not seem like it will work. I tried 20 or so older ones till I found one that would give me a different boot crash point but it still crashes. I can upload a screenshot if needed.
- Second I looked at [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0) This is giving me more questions then answers.

  They suggest to run commands but I am not sure where to run them. I tried it in what I think I can call the GRUB command line (hitting c while booting) and from Ubuntu installer disk using rescue broken system. I did not mount a drive. Both times I got an error.
- Thinking just recovering the files must be a easier option I looked into using [Recovering user files with a Live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78691/recovering-user-files-with-a-live-cd)

I am thinking the reason I am getting stuck on these options is because it is a RAID. I am a little worried also that if I do this step wrong I might mess up my RAID making the problem worse.

So I am assuming you will will need more information to help further but I am not sure what would help. Please let me know and I will gather the info.

Do not see a way to put in my own answer to the question so adding it here.
**Solution:**
I booted up with KNOPPIX Linux Live CD
in terminal type

1. SU
2. mdadm --stop /dev/md0
3. mdadm --stop /dev/md1
4. mdadm --assemble --scan --force

Comment: while in grub I typed ls and it listed a lot of drives and partitions but at the end it had an error message failure reading sector 0xb30 from fd0

Comment: Boot an old kernel

Comment: Thanks for the responses I am reading up on the not syncing post see if that will help. As for boot an old kernel how dose one do that?

Comment: under advanced options I think I found what you describe as old kernels. When I pick a recent one it seems to give the same error. if I pick farther back it still dose not boot but it dose seem to change when it crashes.

Comment: Reading more on Kernel Panic and it says to do the following: Choose another kernel from the grub menu, or run update-initramfs -u -k version to generate the initrd for version then update-grub. But I am not seeing clear instruction on how to do this.

Comment: You mentioned, *"I am hopping for help recovering at lease enough to copy the files off the system."* Although I suspect you'll be able to fix the problem fully, using the information in [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0), you should be able to copy your files off the system even before you fix it, and if your important files (like documents) aren't backed up, you may want to. See [Recovering user files with a Live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78691/recovering-user-files-with-a-live-cd).

Comment: I am trying to understand the best way to ask for help here and I am feeling like I am failing. I am very appreciative of the help I have gotten but while I am sure it is enough of a push for someone more advanced I am failing to see how it will work for my situation. I updated my main post to describe the issues I had with the suggested related posts. I also see people are saying it is a duplicate question but I see no link to the duplicate posts. I will continue to read up on this as I have been but if I could get another nudge I feel it would help a lot.