# Error when reboot after upgrade from 18.10 to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-10, 19.04, 18.10

After I managed to upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04, I got a new problem. After finishing the upgrade, I reboot my laptop but it gets stuck on the purple screen and I restart it again then I got this.

[image: Error]

PS: I run dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu)

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: easiest way is to save your data from a live-session and install anew ubuntu.20.04 (is recommend)  or ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Check that you upgraded to 19.04 & not something else, by default system tools will not *release-upgrade* to a EOL release, so unless you bumped release last year or early-mid Jan-2020 you won't have moved to 19.04 unless you didn't use supported & tested upgrade tools provided by Ubuntu (thus details of what you did might be handy, but I'd still likely recommend a re-install to get to a known state)

Comment: @guiverc if i reinstall it, will I lose all my data? is there any way to save my data?

Comment: @nobody you mean I can save my data by a live ubuntu pendrive????Can you tell me more about it?

Comment: I would always backup data before any re-install (or upgrade etc, using a 'live' media for example to do the backup), but you haven't said if desktop/server/other (by purple screen I'd assume desktop but better if you provide us all details than us guessing), but you can re-install (desktop) using 'something-else' & selecting existing partitions AND ensuring you don't have *format* selected, then it'll note your installed packages, erase system directories, install, add back your additional packages (noted earlier) & ask to reboot. It doesn't touch user data unless format is selected.

Comment: @guiverc I did mention it is laptop and to be honest I didnt backup my data before i reboot my laptop. Can you tell me a little bit detail about ? I can't image how to did that?

Comment: Laptop tells me nothing (many people re-purpose old laptops as low cost/power servers loading Ubuntu Server on them using them as headless servers with lid closed); so tell us to avoid any issues But to backup from 'live' (Ubuntu install media) was also suggested in @nobody's first comment too.  Me, I just mount my hdd/ssd, usually install `nfs-server` (so I can `cp` or `rsync` to network storage) *or* mount backup drive & `cp` or `rsync` there..., but backup however you prefer it; me I usually backup two methods anyway)

Comment: @guiverc, thank you for your help, I will let you know whether i can fix it or not :))

Comment: @guiverc, I backup my data successfully, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Boot a live-session(from pendrive or DVD)

```
sudo fdisk --list
```

search for Type linux ignore swap if present.

Example from my system

```
/dev/sdb1           2048   62916607   62914560    30G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       62916608   71305215    8388608     4G 82 Linux Swap / Solaris
```

start file-manager in live-sesion and mount over that your filesystem.

Plugin an usb-harddrive and mount it too. With

```
findmnt
```

you can see there both filesystem is mounted. Another example from me

```
├─/media/alex/bionic-home             /dev/sdc5            ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
└─/media/alex/bionic                  /dev/sdc1            ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
```

That's my backup-harddrive.

```
sudo cp -a /full/path/to/your/home/on/disk  /full/path/to/usb-drive
```

another example; english is not my native speech.

```
sudo cp -a /home/alex /media/alex/bionic-home
```

Please adapt it to your situation.

from a live-session you need grandet rights, because normally the username from installed system is not the same as in a live-session.

I hope this is understandable for you.

Comment: Thank you, let me try and I will feedback you later

Comment: can I use external hard drive (WD HDD) as back-up hard drive ? because when I run live-session, it didnt recognize my external hard drive

Question 2: As far as I know, you want me to copy all the data in the older version to the back-up hard drive and install the new version over the older. Am I right?

Comment: Save your data in /home/your_username. you need normally only that. If you have set own config parameter for programs in /etc you can save this folder too.  put your harddrive in an usb2 port for test. https://askubuntu.com/questions/78691/recovering-user-files-with-a-live-cd

Comment: so I need 1 pendrive for live-session ubuntu and 1 hard drive for backing up data, right?

Comment: Thank you I did it